SR Flip Flop used as PWM
I came across this question from LT,

and while I understand the basics of the SR Flip-Flop, I'm having trouble determining the gate pulse at the two highlighted regions C &D below.
I don't see any difference in how the SR Flip-Flop behaves in regions C and D. I can find g at region D, but not at region C.

My approach for finding Vg at regions C and D is the same. Please see the images below:

It gives me high for both C & D. Why it is low at region C?

I believe what they're trying to show here is the \$t_{dly1}\$ and \$t_{dly2}\$ times are the times it takes the entire loop to respond to the comparator condition.  What the drawing is showing you is that the condition at BC fulfills the requirement for a high on \$V_g\$, but by the time it propagates to \$V_g\$ you're at CD.  Once the signal has propagated through the loop, only then can \$V_o\$ change direction.
